# `test` comparison behaves differently when sourcing script in current shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a surprising behaviour in a bash script. The script is as follow, I've tried to simplify as much as possible :

test.sh :

```
DBOK=$(sqlplus -s user/xxx as sysdba<<EOF
set feed off pages 0 echo off
SELECT decode(value,'TRUE','CLUSTER','FALSE','NONCLUSTER','UNKNOWN') from v\$parameter where name='cluster_database';
EOF
)
echo x"$DBOK"y
set -x
if [ "${DBOK}" == NONCLUSTER ]; then
echo "not a cluster do nothing"
fi
set +x
```

If I execute this script directly, it works fine :

```
bash ./path/test.sh

    > xNONCLUSTERy
    > ++ '[' NONCLUSTER == NONCLUSTER ']'
    > ++ echo 'not a cluster do nothing'
    > ++ set +x
```

But if I run the script in "dot space slash" mode (as required : the final target is to modify the env of current process), it doesn't work :

```
. /path/test.sh

test

    xNONCLUSTERy
    ++ '[' 'NONCLUSTER' == NONCLUSTER ']'
    ++ set +x
```

Loading variable as a result of the sql script works fine and result appears to be good. But when coming to the test comparison, it looks like running the script in the current process spoils it ???

Any help would be appreciated, I'm dry !

**Edit with hexdump command following Adrian's comment :**

$ ./test.sh

```
00000000  4e 4f 4e 43 4c 55 53 54  45 52 0a |NONCLUSTER.| 
0000000b 
xNONCLUSTERy
++ [[ NONCLUSTER == NONCLUSTER ]]
++ echo 'not a cluster do nothing' not a cluster do nothing
++ set +x
```

$ . ./test.sh

```
00000000  1b 5d 30 3b 6f 72 61 63  6c 65 40 6e 61 74 71 6f  |.]0;oracle@natqo|
00000010  72 61 30 34 3a 7e 2f 73  63 72 69 70 74 73 2f 74  |ra04:~/scripts/t|
00000020  6f 6f 6c 73 20 7c 20 73  71 6c 70 6c 75 73 20 2d  |ools | sqlplus -|
00000030  73 20 6c 65 64 62 61 40  51 42 4f 41 55 44 49 54  |s ledba@QBOAUDIT|
00000040  20 61 73 20 73 79 73 64  62 61 07 4e 4f 4e 43 4c  | as sysdba.NONCL|
00000050  55 53 54 45 52 0a                                 |USTER.|
00000056
xNONCLUSTERy
++ [[ NONCLUSTER == NONCLUSTER ]]
++ set +x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your *default* shell isn't `bash` as you think. You're using Bash syntax with the `==` and normal non-bash test doesn't recognize `==`. Two choices:

- Use `=` as your test instead of `==`. This will work in all Posix based shells and the original Bourne Shell.
- Add `#! /bin/bash` to the top of your script to guarantee you're using Bash and not some other shell. Never assume the shell. And, if you're going all Bash, use `[[ ... ]]` in your test instead of `[ ... ]`. This will work in Kornshell, Dash, and Ash shells too.

Even if `/bin/sh` is linked to `/bin/bash`, Bash doesn't behave like Bash when called via `sh`. Instead, it allegedly operates in pure POSIX mode. (I say allegedly because Kornshell is a full POSIX compliant shell, and I know that certain things that Kornshell does won't work in `/bin/sh`).

On Mac OS X, `/bin/sh` is linked to `/bin/bash`. On Linux systems, they use either the Ash or Dash shell for `/bin/sh` which is suppose to be more POSIX compliant.

Comment: #! /bin/bash solved the problem. I shouldn't have trusted $SHELL nor any other test. Thanks to Adrian and David !

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I said? Also, *"on Linux systems"* is a wrong generalization, not every Linux distribution defaults to `ash` or `dash` for `/bin/sh`. Debian and derivations might, but Debian != all of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Which shell are you running when sourcing the script?

Since the output does not look the same (`NOCLUSTER` vs. `'NOCLUSTER'`) I assume it's not the same shell and that your currently running shell might not tolerate `==` in combination with single bracket notation which is not portable (but most modern shells permit it).

You should either use `[ ... = ... ]` *or* `[[ ... == ... ]]` for shells that support it. I usually stick to single bracket notation unless I specifically need a feature that only comes with `[[` like the `=~` operator.

I can't seem to reproduce this:

```
$ /bin/bash --noprofile --norc
```

.

```
bash-4.2$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash

foo=NONCLUSTER
set -x
[ "${foo}" = NONCLUSTER ]    && echo true || echo false
[ "${foo}" == NONCLUSTER ]   && echo true || echo false
[[ "${foo}" == NONCLUSTER ]] && echo true || echo false
```

.

```
bash-4.2$ ./t.sh
+ '[' NONCLUSTER = NONCLUSTER ']'
+ echo true
true
+ '[' NONCLUSTER == NONCLUSTER ']'
+ echo true
true
+ [[ NONCLUSTER == NONCLUSTER ]]
+ echo true
true
```

.

```
bash-4.2$ . ./t.sh
++ '[' NONCLUSTER = NONCLUSTER ']'
++ echo true
true
++ '[' NONCLUSTER == NONCLUSTER ']'
++ echo true
true
++ [[ NONCLUSTER == NONCLUSTER ]]
++ echo true
true
```

.

```
bash-4.2$ sh t.sh
+ sh t.sh
+ [ NONCLUSTER = NONCLUSTER ]
+ echo true
true
+ [ NONCLUSTER == NONCLUSTER ]
t.sh: 6: [: NONCLUSTER: unexpected operator
+ echo false
false
+ [[ NONCLUSTER == NONCLUSTER ]]
t.sh: 7: t.sh: [[: not found
+ echo false
false
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, Adrian. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue. The shell is /bin/bash and I tested all combinations of single/double brackets with = or ==, but I have the same result. However I have now  [[ NONCLUSTER == NONCLUSTER ]] in the "dot space slash mode" ?!

Comment: I updated my post, I can't reproduce the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks again Adrian. I have the same feedback as you have (except that I don't have error with "sh t.sh", but my "sh" command links to bash, so it logically works). As you can see, I have enclosed my variable with x and y to check there is no extra character, but I must suppose there is, as a result of an sql oracle query ? This tiny error is a real nightmare and I don't see any workaround or alternative way to test ...! Atb.

Comment: My `sh` is also `bash` but that doesn't explain why it works. If invoked as `sh` `bash` goes into `POSIX`-compatibility mode so actually it should not work unless this behavior changed but I can't find anything that would support this assumption in the `bash` changelog. Which version of `bash` do you use? I would agree but I tested reading in non-printable characters from a file I generated and the output of `set -x` clearly shows the variable holds special characters (well, my shell anyway) so I don't think that's that either. But you should still check by doing e.g. `hexdump -C <<< "$DBOK"`.

Comment: Bingo Adrian, you're great ! I come back with the complete explanation but basically my variable doesn't contain what it appeared to contain in "dot space slash" mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yet no explanation on such behaviour but workaround is to load variable in 2 steps :

```
sqlplus -s ledba/xxx as sysdba<<EOF
spool /tmp/test.lst
set feed off pages 0 echo off
SELECT decode(value,'TRUE','CLUSTER','FALSE','NONCLUSTER','INCONNU') from v\$parameter where name='cluster_database';
spool off
EOF
DBOK=`cat /tmp/test.lst|sed 's/ *$//'`
```

Then comparison can proceed without trouble...

Anyway, thanks to Adrian for his precious time !